# How to get plid of a portlet in .vm?

Tags: portlet, liferay-6

I need to retreive the **plid** of a portlet in my **theme(.vm).**

Can't find an appropriate way to do this.

I need to open My Account portlet as a popup. The code for this is to be written in the theme.

I am using

```
#set ($my_url = $portletURLFactory.create($request, "2", $getterUtil.getLong($plid), "RENDER_PHASE"))
```

and then using the url in anchor tag:

```
<a style="color: #ffffff" href="$my_URL">Click Here</a>
```

But on click i am redirected to blank page.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to get plid(pageId in vm)

#set ($themeDisplay = $request.get('theme-display'))

```
#set ($currentPlid = $getterUtil.getLong($themeDisplay.get('plid')))
```